# Error: Syntax error. Found 'a.Annual_LED_Revenue__c' in visual force page

Tags: visualforce

Can any one help me out with this

> Error :Syntax error. Found 'a.Annual_LED_Revenue__c' .

I have a vf page created on standard "quote" object.I wanted few fields from Account object .So i referred the using Quote.Account in repeat tag with the variable as"a",but the system is throwing error for few of the fields in the account object which i have highlighted in Bold.Any help is very much appreciated.

VF CODE using  HTML :

```
<h2>Justification and Account Information</h2>
    <table class="bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">RFQ Justification</td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Main Customers of Account:</td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Bridgelux Competition at Account:</td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Geographic regions serviced:</td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Annual lighting revenue:</td> 
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Annual LED revenue or percent:</td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Annual Purchases of LED Sources (SAM):</td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Percent of LED purchases that are COB:</td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Other Info:</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <apex:repeat value="{!Quote.Account}" var="a">
            <tr>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!a.name}"/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!a.Main_Customers_of_Account__c}"/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputField value="{!a.Bridgelux_Competition_at_Account__c}"/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputField value="{!a.Servicing_Region__c}"/></td>
               **<!-- <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputField value="{!a.Annual_LED_Revenue__c"/> </td>-->**
               **<!-- <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputField value="{!a.Annual_LED_Revenue__c}"/></td>-->**
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputField value="{!a.Annual_Purchases_of_LED_Sources_SAM__c}"/> </td>
                **<!--<td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputField value="{!a.Percent_of_LED_purchases_that_are_COB__c"/></td>-->**
                <!--<td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputField value="{!a.Percent_of_LED_purchases_that_are_COB__c"/></td>-->
            </tr>
            </apex:repeat>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: You are missing the closing `}` in `value="{!a.Annual_LED_Revenue__c"`.

Comment: Keith -- you might want to add your comment as the answer so Nikkey can cross this one off the list (plus I know you are desperate for reputation points :-)